# Cordova - Implementing the Privacy Screen functionality with the ASWebAuthenticationSession usage

Tags: objective-c, cordova

I'm adding the privacy screen functionality to the hybrid Cordova app via a plugin and following [the approach adviced by apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1838/_index.html).

Though it leads to unexpected issues when I open ASWebAuthenticationSession window I use for the OAuth authentication. What happens is, when system dialogue appears with a text "Your app wants to use xxx for Sign In", it makes the app to lose a focus and the privacy screen appears behind the overlay. After I choose "Yes", the app gains focus back and the code removing the privacy screen fires, the same code also closes the freshly opened ASWebAuthenticationSession window.

The code in PrivacyScreenPlugin.m:

```
UIViewController *blankViewController;

@interface PrivacyScreenPlugin ()
@end

@implementation PrivacyScreenPlugin

- (void)pluginInitialize
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onAppDidBecomeActive:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onPageDidLoad) name:CDVPageDidLoadNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onAppWillResignActive:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
}


-(UIViewController *)createViewWithGradient {
    UIViewController *viewController;
    viewController = [UIViewController new];
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
    return viewController;
}

-(void) applyPrivacyScreen
{
    if (blankViewController == NULL) {
        blankViewController = [self createViewWithGradient];
    }

    blankViewController.view.window.hidden = NO;
    [self.viewController.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:blankViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
}


#pragma mark - Explicit Commands
- (void) hidePrivacyScreen:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    [self removePrivacyScreen];
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}

- (void) showPrivacyScreen:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    [self applyPrivacyScreen];
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}


#pragma mark - Triggered functions
- (void) onPageDidLoad
{
    [self removePrivacyScreen];
}

- (void)onAppDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self removePrivacyScreen];
}

- (void)onAppWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self applyPrivacyScreen];
}

#pragma mark - Helper functions
-(void) removePrivacyScreen
{
    [self.viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}

@end
```

So far I got that issue is related to the way view is dismissed, namely [dismissViewControllerAnimated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismissviewcontrolleranimated?language=objc) which dismisses the stack of modal windows:

```
[self.viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Can it be helped or worked around? Maybe instead of removing a security screen, it can be hidden? Or is there a different way to draw the overlay which is free of the issue?

P.S. I tried to listen to `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` event, but it's not what I want. I'd like the app screen to be covered as soon as it's sent to the list of apps (via a double tap on the home button or long swipe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish it, it's needed to render the privacy screen in a subview, instead of a modal view. It enables to hide/show a privacy screen view instead of adding/removing it:

```
-(void) removePrivacyScreen
 {
    blankViewController.view.hidden=YES;
 }


 -(void) applyPrivacyScreen
 {
     if (blankViewController == NULL) {
         blankViewController = [self createViewWithGradient];
     }

    blankViewController.view.hidden = NO;    
    [self.viewController.view.window addSubview:blankViewController.view];
 }
```